# Need a css file for advance data grid

Tags: apache-flex

Please any one send me the css file to have good look n feel for advance datagrid.

Answer (score 3):

Use the FlexStyle Explorer and look at the Data-Grid on the left-pane.
Style it to your heart's content and copy the css from the right pane.

http://demo.borland.com/flex/SilkTest13.0/3.4/Flex3TestApp/Flex3TestApp.html

Comment: any one have cool .css file for advance datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial has a section on how to style a datagrid. I'd suggest learning how to create the CSS yourself: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-fun-advanced-datagrid-topics